# Oauth 2 authentication in nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-services, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am in process of developing a POC as a part of technology overhaul.
For this i have developed a couple of Service endpoints using HAPI. I want to secure these web-services using Oauth 2.0 mechanism.
2 options that i have:

```
- Using the oauth2.0 support of npm which comes for express.
- Manually create the keys, share and then encrypt/decrypt.(node-rsa)
```

Being a novice to Nodejs i am unable to find a solid path for accomplishing this, and am a little skeptical.
Any help or examples would be really appriciated.
-V

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with Hapi I'd suggest leveraging the [Bell](https://github.com/hapijs/bell) plugin.

Support baked in for common third-party providers, but you can easily create a custom provider (detailed in the API docs).